# PopupWindow above Virtual keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, popupwindow

I have a PopupWindow that is shown when a user is typing in an EditText. This popup offers him some suggestions.
My problem is that when the Popup is shown, a part of it is displayed over the Keyboard on the screen, preventing the user to continue typing.
Does anyone know why of this behaviour and how could I fix it?

Comment: can you post the PopupWindow code?

Comment: It's normal behavior of popup. Where should it be? There may be no space at all above keyboard (on small screens)

Comment: Yeah, the position of the popup on the screen is correct, but I want to have the keyboard always in front, not covered by the popup. For example, looking at the behaviour of AutoCompleteView, the dropdown view doesn't cover the virtual keyboard. I wanted to achieve that same result.

Answer (score 13):

To have your popupwindow behind the softkeyboard just set this line:

```
popupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
```

and also

```
popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
popupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
```

This is working with lollipop

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
PopupWindow.showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)
```

instead of

`PopupWindow.showAsDropDown (View anchor)`