# PopupWindow changes position as keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557625/popupwindow-above-virtual-keyboard) question. I experienced the same issue, and the answers to the linked question have resolved it. Unfortunately, a side-effect is that as the PopupWindow resizes itself to make space for the keyboard, it also moves it's position upward.

Is there a way to have the PopupWindow resize but keep it's original position?